# Certain fonts look too small after upgrading

Tags: unity, nautilus, fonts

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 today and after that certain fonts are looking smaller than they were before, I tried changing that from the GNOME-tweak-tool as well as Unity-tweak tool, The size increases in Chrome and other Windows but does not in nautilus as well as the tabs in Chrome

I am currently using Unity (The one which came default with 14.04), the fonts before:

[image]

The fonts in nautilus are small as well as the ones for the tab names,
This is after increasing the font size:

[image]

The bookmark size increased but the filename font size as well as the tab caption did not.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu changed certain fonts, maybe that's why.

Comment: After the upgrade I had the same problem but installing infinality (
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html ) worked for me. Hope it helps. Anyway It's just a workaround.

Comment: @braiam How do I change it back then?

Answer (score 2):

One way to "tweak" this might be:

System Settings > Display > **Scale for menu and title bars**

- which is available as separate setting for every monitor you have (e.g. if you have several).

**Scale all windows to match:**

- ... to the right of the above might also be of some help.

Comment: The problem is that "Scale for menu and title bars" also affects terminal fonts, some selected fonts in web browser and other random fonts all over the system and really confuses the user

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading. Desktop and Nautilus was too small, but tweak tool didn't help.
Since the problem doesn't occur with a new account, I tried to narrow it down by renaming these files from my home directory

```
.gconf
.gnome2
.gnome2_private
.gnome
```

to see what Ubuntu is doing when they are missing, and after re-login the fonts in Nautilus and on desktop were normal again. I just had to configure the console layout settings again, since these settings were gone with the new files. So any of the files is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and it will resolve your problem:
Open "System Settings", select "Universal Access". On the first tab marked "Seeing" there is a drop-down field marked "Text size". Adjust the text size to Large or Larger.